# I would like to return either even or odd as a string but for some reason this code keeps returning undefined.

Tags: javascript

```
function EvenOdd(num) {
    if (num === 0)
        return 'even';
    if (num == 1)
        return 'odd';
    num -= 2;
    EvenOdd(num);
}
console.log(EvenOdd(49));
return 0;
```

This returns undefined every time regardless of input. I notice that when I run the debugger that it doesn't exit the function even if I have return statements.

Comment: Your recursive call is missing `return`.

Comment: You should add error handling for negative numbers and things that are not numbers, otherwise you'll infinitely recurse.

Comment: Not to mention that recursion is a absolutely terrible approach to determine whether or not a number is even or odd.

Answer (score 2):

> This returns undefined every time regardless of input

No, it doesn't.

If you enter `0`, it returns `'even'`.

If you enter `1`, it returns `'odd'`.

If you enter anything else then (after a lot of recursive calling of itself) it returns nothing **because there is no return statement** for that case.

If you want to return whatever it is you get back from calling it recursively, then you have to actually do that.

```
num -= 2;
return EvenOdd(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a mod against 2 to see if it is even or odd, right you you check against the number itself (which 49 doesn't equal 0 or 1):

```js
function EvenOdd(num) {
    if (num % 2 === 0)
        return 'even';
    else
        return 'odd';
}
console.log(EvenOdd(49));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function EvenOdd(num) {
     return (num % 2) ? 'Odd' : 'Even';
}
console.log(EvenOdd(48));
```

Answer (score 0):

There a many things wrong with your function.

First, you need to `return` something inside you function, that's why you see `undefined`.

Then, to know if a number is `odd` or `even`, you can simply us a modulo : `%`

```js
const EvenOdd = n => n % 2 == 0 ? 'Even' : 'Odd';
console.log(EvenOdd(49));
```